# Chi-squared test with scipy: what's the difference between chi2_contingency and chisquare?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, python, scipy

I'd like to run a chi-squared test in Python with scipy. I've created code to do this, but I don't know if what I'm doing is right, because the scipy docs are quite sparse.

Background first: I have two groups of users. My null hypothesis is that there is no significant difference in whether people in either group are more likely to use desktop, mobile, or tablet.

These are the *observed* frequencies in the two groups:

```
[[u'desktop', 14452], [u'mobile', 4073], [u'tablet', 4287]]
[[u'desktop', 30864], [u'mobile', 11439], [u'tablet', 9887]]
```

Here is my code using [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html):

```
obs = np.array([14452, 4073, 4287], [30864, 11439, 9887])
chi2, p, dof, expected = stats.chi2_contingency(obs)
print p
```

This gives me a p-value of `2.02258737401e-38`, which clearly is significant.

My question is: does this code look valid? In particular, I'm not sure whether I should be using [scipy.stats.chi2_contingency](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) or [scipy.stats.chisquare](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare.html), given the data I have.

Answer (score 13):

Your code is valid. You use `chi2_contingency` when you want to test whether two (or more) groups have the save distribution. Null hypothesis: the two groups have no significant difference.

You use `chisquare` when you want to test whether one (discrete) random variable has a specific distribution. Null hypothesis: the random variable is not significantly different from the specified distribution.

For example, you toss a coin 1100 times and get 553 heads 547 tails. You hypothesize it has a probability of 0.5 to get a head.

```
>> _, pvalue = chisquare([553, 547], [1100 * 0.5, 1100 * 0.5])
>> print(pvalue)
0.8564407259982999
```

So p > 0.1, it's not significant, you don't reject the hypothesis.

In summary, you use `chi2_contingency` when you don't know the underlying distribution but you want to test whether two (or more) groups have the same distribution. You use `chisquare` when you have a distribution in mind and you want to test whether a group matches that distribution.

Answer (score 11):

Probably you have solved it, but I let this here to help anyone that is lost, like I was. The difference is the ***Null Hypothesis***.

***scipy.stats.chi2_contingency***, from [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html):

> "Chi-square test of independence of variables in a contingency table"

In this test you are testing if there is there is relationship between two or more variable. This is called  ***chi-square test for independence***, also called ***Pearson's chi-square test*** or ***the chi-square test of association***. In this test you are testing the association between two or more variable. The null hupothesis, in your example, is **"there is no effect of group in choosing the equipment to use"**.

In ***scipy.stats.chisquare*** from [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)

> "The chi square test tests the null hypothesis that the categorical
>   data has the given frequencies."

Here you are comparing if there is difference between an observation and an expected frequency. So, the null hupothesis, is that **"there isn't any difference between observed and the expected"**. Here, the test is used to compare the observed sample distribution with the expected probability distribution. This is named ***Chi-Square goodness of fit test***

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I've updated the answer, I hope you can understand now.

Comment: It sounds like the answer intends to indicate that one function conducts a chi-square test of association and one conducts a chi-square goodness-of-fit test.  But at the time of writing, I still don't think this is very clear in the answer. In particular, I think describing the latter test as comparing observed values and expected values doesn't clearly differentiate it from the chi-square test of association.